# My Windows Store is missing from Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-store

I was having problems with my Windows Store. It wouldn't open! I would click its icon, and all I get is a quick flash of the screen, so I did some searching on Google and came across [this thread](http://forums.windowscentral.com/ask-question/371651-why-wont-app-store-open-windows-10-a.html). I did *everything* suggested there, and still my Windows Store won't work.

Now I don't even have a `WinStore` folder in `C:\Windows\`

When I type `Store` into Cortana I get the following:

[image]

Some people have suggested that one does an `In Place Upgrade` whatever that is, but I can't do that since I had originally upgraded from Windows 8.1 Pro to Windows 10. I don't have any installation media for Windows 10.

I've tried what is suggested by Ankur, but I get the following:

[image: error on reset]

What am I to do? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue... what I did was this...
Run PowerShell as Administrator

After doing so... execute this command:

```
get-appxpackage -allusers
```

Actual Result:

```
IsDevelopmentMode      : False

Name                   : Microsoft.Messaging
Publisher              : CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
Architecture           : X86
ResourceId             :
Version                : 2.13.20000.0
PackageFullName        : Microsoft.Messaging_2.13.20000.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe
InstallLocation        : C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.Messaging_2.13.20000.0_x86__8wekyb3d8bbwe
IsFramework            : False
PackageFamilyName      : Microsoft.Messaging_8wekyb3d8bbwe
PublisherId            : 8wekyb3d8bbwe
PackageUserInformation : {S-1-5-21-3086552607-807654742-197948547-1001 [Roel Reyes]: Staged,
                         S-1-5-21-3086552607-807654742-197948547-500 [Administrator]: Installed}
IsResourcePackage      : False
IsBundle               : False
IsDevelopmentMode      : False

Name                   : Microsoft.WindowsStore
Publisher              : CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
Architecture           : X64
ResourceId             :
Version                : 2015.25.22.0
PackageFullName        : Microsoft.WindowsStore_2015.25.22.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
InstallLocation        : C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsStore_2015.25.22.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
IsFramework            : False
PackageFamilyName      : Microsoft.WindowsStore_8wekyb3d8bbwe
PublisherId            : 8wekyb3d8bbwe
PackageUserInformation : {S-1-5-21-3086552607-807654742-197948547-500 [Administrator]: Installed}
IsResourcePackage      : False
IsBundle               : False
IsDevelopmentMode      : False

Name                   : Microsoft.Windows.Photos
Publisher              : CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
Architecture           : X64
ResourceId             :
Version                : 16.122.14020.0
PackageFullName        : Microsoft.Windows.Photos_16.122.14020.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
InstallLocation        : C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.Windows.Photos_16.122.14020.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
IsFramework            : False
PackageFamilyName      : Microsoft.Windows.Photos_8wekyb3d8bbwe
PublisherId            : 8wekyb3d8bbwe
PackageUserInformation : {S-1-5-21-1172717557-2008772951-1947940980-11352 [TRENDPH\RoelR]: Installed,
                         S-1-5-21-3086552607-807654742-197948547-1001 [Roel Reyes]: Staged,
                         S-1-5-21-3086552607-807654742-197948547-500 [Administrator]: Staged,
                         S-1-5-21-1172717557-2008772951-1947940980-52298 [TRENDPH\a-lesliemo]: Staged}
IsResourcePackage      : False
IsBundle               : False
IsDevelopmentMode      : False
```

Search for Microsoft.WindowsStore:

```
Name                   : Microsoft.WindowsStore
Publisher              : CN=Microsoft Corporation, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=Washington, C=US
Architecture           : X64
ResourceId             :
Version                : 2015.25.22.0
PackageFullName        : Microsoft.WindowsStore_2015.25.22.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
InstallLocation        : C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsStore_2015.25.22.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
IsFramework            : False
PackageFamilyName      : Microsoft.WindowsStore_8wekyb3d8bbwe
PublisherId            : 8wekyb3d8bbwe
PackageUserInformation : {S-1-5-21-3086552607-807654742-197948547-500 [Administrator]: Installed}
IsResourcePackage      : False
IsBundle               : False
IsDevelopmentMode      : False
```

Execute the 2nd command:

```
Add-AppxPackage -register "C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\amd64_microsoft-windows-store-client-app_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.10586.0_none_0c306efaf8a72c36.manifest" -DisableDevelopmentMode
```

Then That's it :) Hope It works on you since it worked on me

Comment: When I try and run the 2nd command, I get a red error saying `An invalid manifest file name was passed to this function` :(

Comment: I get the same error too. Add-AppxPackage : An invalid manifest file name was passed to this function. This file must be named AppxManifest.xml

Answer (score -1):

I will suggest you to follow the below given steps:

1. Press **Windows key** and **R key** together to open Run
2. Type **wsreset.exe** and press Enter button
3. Restart the PC and sign in with Microsoft User account.

Hope this information will help you to solve the issue. 
Thank you.

Comment: Tried, but got an error :( See updated Q.